# How to find which dynamic button is clicked in android

Tags: android, button

i have created dynamic button in activity on button click. When i created more than on button in activity,onclick works for the most recent button as i assigned id to every button. how can i identify which dynamic button is pressed other than most recent button. 
Here is the snippet of my code

```
public void dynamicButton()
    {
       // int x=0;
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(TimeStudy.this);
        value = preferences.getInt("value", 0);
        //myButton = new Button(this);



          //  if (value > x)
        if ( i <= value) {
               myButton= new Button(this);
               myButton.setId(value);
               BtnId.add(value);
               myButton.setTag(value);

                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamiclayout);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                ll.setPadding(10, 300, 10, 10);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                myButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
                btnid= myButton.getId();
                myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       switch (btnid) {
                           case 1:case 2:case 3:case 
                               Intent intent = new Intent(TimeStudy.this, CollectSample.class);
                           startActivity(intent);
                               break;
                       }

                    }
                });

                ll.addView(myButton, lp);
                i++;

            }
        switch (btnid) {
            case 1:case 2:case 3:
                    SharedPreferences average = getSharedPreferences("avg", 0);
                String avgbtn = average.getString("btnavg", "");


                settings = getSharedPreferences("dynamicbtname", 0);
                btnname = settings.getString("btnname", "");
                ar.add(btnname);

                String styledText = "<font color='#008000'>" + btnname + "</font>" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp"
                        + "<small>"
                        + avgbtn + "</font>"
                        + "<small>";
                myButton.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));

                myButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
                break;
        }
```

i want result like this even if after creation of all three button and 1 button is clicked no shows on first button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk8JZ.png)

i get this if i pressed 1 button after creation of 2 or third button data returns to most recent button. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbMw0.png)

any help appriciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

THere's two ways.

1)Check by comparing it to the view variable passed in

2)Use an OnClickListener implementation that knows which one it is (by using different classes, or using one class with a parameter in it).

Comment: can you elaborate how view variable can be compared.

Comment: i use view.gettag(); 
2 buttons have different tags but it still return number on button 2 even when tag value is when i use switch for setting number